# Passing array object from one window to another

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Passing array content value into another window array content.

Window FirstWindow

```
 var firstData = [ {title:'Abcd',disc:'1234'},{title:'egg',disc:'567'}];
```

second Window

```
var secondData = [];
```

How to pass FirstWindow object into second window array object Titanium

```
var window  = Alloy.createController('SecondWindow').getView();
window.secondData = firstData;
open.Window();
```

For me its not working 
when open window its still empty.

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in the second window

```
this.secondData = [];
```

and it should work.

or

```
var secondData = [];
this.setSecondData = function(e){
    secondData = e;
}
```

and on the first window:

```
var c = Alloy.createController('SecondWindow')  
c.setSecondData(firstData);
var window  = c.getView();
```

Alternatively you can pass any arguments in the createController function:
[createController](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy-method-createController)

Comment: Alloy.createController('SecondWindow', firstData).getView();  Inside arugment i pass like this at second window var secondData = arguments[0];  It saying its not an object and crash

Comment: i am using Alloy!!   var Window  = Alloy.createController('SecondWindow').getView();
  Window.setSecondData(firstData);Script Error = 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'SecondData.length') at SecondWindow.js (line 54)

Comment: apply setSecondData function to controller. please check my edited reply

Comment: i try it its giving me empty value